# Diference Connecting AC/DC

Tags: dc, ac

Why is there a difference between how AC is connected and how DC is connected? For DC, the polarity of the connection matters, but for AC it doesn't.

Comment: You have to include a lot more context, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @jippie He is just asking why inverting the DC supply wires to a device is a problem and inverting the AC supply wires isn't. (Although I see some confusion in the way he asks)

Answer (score 3):

**AC supply**

Is a periodic function like a sinusoidal wave. It goes both +Ve and -Ve at regular intervals of time. So if we even interchange the supply terminals, it would just make everything negative i.e. +Ve becomes -Ve while -Ve again becomes +Ve and hence both the RMS value and average value of measurable quantities remains same over the time of measurement which is generally quite high as compared to the time period of one cycle.

*Also it will matter if the AC Supply is not symmetric for the periods when it is +Ve and -Ve, even then interchanging the supply terminals will make a difference.*

**DC Supply**

The supply is constant hence the potential of one supply terminal is at some constant difference from the other so interchanging the supply terminal will change the new supply to negative of the original one, hence changing all voltage and current parameters to -Ve.

Answer (score 2):

> Why we can connect positive terminal to either positive or negative
>   terminal in case of AC supply only?

Often AC supplies will feed a transformer or a bridge rectifier and neither of these components require any particular polarization of the signal. For a transformer, the signal must alternate for the transformer to work correctly. For the bridge, it doesn't care whether the feed to it alternates or is constant dc of either polarity.

This means the wires can be changed over and the result is the same.

On the other hand, my android phone expects to see positive dc on one pin and negative (return, or 0V) on the other pin and if I reversed the connection I may get smoke or, I may get a blank screen. There's also the possibility that it may work perfectly i.e. it has a bridge rectifier inside it but this is unlikely.

It's worth mentioning that on an AC supply it would be unusual to call one terminal positive and one terminal negative - maybe AC1 and AC2 or ~1 and ~2 or just ~ and ~.